# Decimal string without decimals, dots or commas in any culture

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, invariantculture

If I have a simple decimal in C#, and I want to `ToString` it without any dots, commas or decimals in any culture - how do i do it?

I tried the `ToString("N0")` with `invariantculture` which removes decimals, but it adds "." in my language.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Do you want all the decimal numbers to show, just without a delimiter?  (i.e `3.14` becomes `314`)?

Comment: @maccettura Nope, ignore decimals

Comment: Ok so `3.14` should become `3`?

Comment: F0: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.85).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb

Comment: @HansPassant You should post that as an answer, it's exactly what's needed for this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't clarified in the comments yet, but I suspect you want something like this?

`3.14 -> 3`

`5.34543543 -> 5`

If that is correct then you simply need to cast your `decimal` to an `int` which would strip the precision off and give you *just* the whole number.

```
string someString = ((int)someDecimal).ToString();
```

If you find yourself repeating this logic often you can make a simple extension method to keep it DRY:

```
public static class DecimalExtensions
{
    public static string ToIntString(this decimal input)
    {
        return ((int)input).ToString();
    }
}
```

And simply call it like so:

```
string someString = someDecimal.ToIntString();
```

Simple fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eDCmk5)

### EDIT

@HansPassant actually gave the simplest solution in the comments and I feel silly for not remembering:

```
string someString = someDecimal.ToString("F0", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This is a *much* better answer and if Hans posts an answer I suggest marking theirs as the solution.

Comment: Great example that when your mind is caught in some culture/tostring stuff, the simplest solution is just obvious and easy. Thanks for showing how stupid I was - I will mark as answer in 6 minutes ;-)

Comment: @LarsHoldgaard I just edited and added an extension method example too if you find it useful.

Comment: Agreed with the edit. May not be the most readable, but definitely the most succinct, and you don't have to do any additional method calls.

Comment: Make sure format does not use group separators - I never can remember if `ToString` could produce something like `1,000,000`... I'd personally explicitly specify `InvariantCulture` to be sure...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to maccettura's answer which will only work for numbers between (2^31)-1 and -(2^31)-1. You can use:

```
decimal.Truncate(decimalToTruncate)
```

which should work for all values that a decimal can store.

[Simple fiddle by maccettura](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZH4xRH)

[Decimal.Truncate on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.truncate(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Nice, didnt know about that method

Comment: No problem. I don't know if it's any better than just doing it your way or not, but it's always good to know that there *are* multiple ways of doing things.

Comment: I think your way is much simpler and accounts for any number in the decimal range.  I upvoted.  I also made a simple fiddle for it [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZH4xRH) if you want to include it in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is just use Convert.ToInt32("Your Value") instead of .ToString().

So

string result= Convert.ToInt32("3.14").ToString();

It will give you "3" as result.